# Back to back support

Tags: expressions

In a (software) business negotiation to provide a joint service with a partner, the potential partner would like to provide "back to back support" for the joint service.

What does back to back support in this context mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Back to back support* is a term of art in computerized applications that use so-called "shared service agreements". Let's say that Company A wishes to offer goods and services to customers say by phone or website, and to that end they purchase and operate computer hardware (e.g., servers) or software (e.g., inventory programs) from company X.  Company X is said to be the OEM, the Original Equipment Manufacturer, and Company X's products are called (somewhat redundantly) *OEM equipment*. This term is misleading because company X may be merely repacking equipment from company Y, which is the actual manufacturer.

Company A will have to provide customer support for its application in case customers are having problems, and if a problem can be traced to the  OEM equipment, Company A will have to rely on the customer service of Company X, which may have to rely, in turn, on the customer service of Company Y. All of which, is fine because there are direct customer relationships in the chain

> User->A->X->Y

The problem arises when Company A decides to outsource some or all of its customer service to Company Q. Company Q didn't buy the OEM equipment from Company X -- Company A did that -- and there's no reason why Company X would be responsive to the requests for help from Company Q. Thus Company A will require that Company Q have an independent relationship with Company X for support of Company X's OEM equipment. This is called back to back support.

Here's a paragraph from a [RFB](https://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/content/pdfs/SIOM100516_AN.pdf) (request for bid) from the Bank of India:

> The bidder should be authorised partner of OEM and should be having
>   back to back support of Original Equipment Manufacturers (OEM) for the
>   equipment included in the proposed solution. The **back to back
>   Support** agreement with OEM should include the activities such as
>   Technical Assistance support, Spares support, Software upgradation
>   support.

Answer (score -1):

We use the term back-to-back generally to what happens successively, as in 'back-to-back victories. (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back-to-back)

Back-to-back stands for 'coming one after the other'. (Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary.) In a joint service, when a partner offers back-to-back support, it means that he would provide consecutive support. If you take care of a call, he would take care of the next call.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the meaning of [consecutive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consecutive) (synonymous with *back-to-back* in the case you quote of *back-to-back victories*), it does not mean alternating service as you suggest in your final paragraph